# Select all inputs, labels, selects etc within THIS - each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm working on some complicated form at the moment.

Just wondering, is there any better way to do this:

```
$('.selector').each( function(){

    $("input", this).prop('disabled', true);
    $("select", this).prop('disabled', true);
    $("label", this).prop('disabled', true);
    $("textarea", this).prop('disabled', true);

});
```

I want to select all inputs within `this` (currently looped through `.selector`).
Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Yes, technically. Although @BoltClock's answer below is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's fine, but to simplify it you should be able to use the comma as you would to group any other selectors:

```
$('.selector').each(function() {
    $('input, select, label, textarea', this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

If the only thing you're doing is setting that property on those elements, then you don't really need the `.each()` loop. You can safely drop that and reduce it to this one-liner:

```
$('input, select, label, textarea', '.selector').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Is `$(".selector input, .selector select, .selector label, .selector textarea").prop('disabled', true);` equivalent?

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt: It should be. Also, `$('.selector').find('input, select, label, textarea').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: Neat. I wonder if there's any performance difference between them.